# Stored Procedure is not updating database C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

This is my first time posting, so please let me know if I made a mistake or if my question is poorly worded. I am currently working on an utility app that allows data from several different csv files to be uploaded into a database for reporting purposes.The App takes the files, combines them, and removes duplicates. Once the database is generated any new file can be uploaded to update the database or insert new records.

I looked around and I couldn't find a solution for my problem. At the moment I am having trouble updating the database with new data.

For some reason, whenever I try to update the data using the following stored procedure, none of the changes are saved in the database.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDeviceReport] 
    @SerialNumber AS VARCHAR(32),
    @DeviceType AS VARCHAR(8),
    @InstalledOn AS VARCHAR(32),
    @PortStatus AS CHAR(6)
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE computer
    SET deviceType = @DeviceType, deviceInstalledOn = @InstalledOn
    WHERE serialID = @SerialNumber

    UPDATE computer_localblocker
    SET portStatus = @PortStatus
    WHERE computer_serialid = @SerialNumber;
END
GO
```

Here is the C# code that executes the procedure.

```
 public void updateOrgDevices()
 {
     using (var conn = new SqlConnection(PopulateDatabase.connectionString))
     {
            int debug = 0;

            conn.Open();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DictionaryObjs> element in GlobalVariables.UpdateData)
            {
                OrgDevRepObj obj = element.Value as OrgDevRepObj;

                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("UpdateDeviceReport", conn);
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@SerialNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 32).Value = obj.SerialNumber.Trim().ToUpper();
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DeviceType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8).Value = obj.DeviceType;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@InstalledOn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 32).Value = obj.InstalledOn;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@PortStatus", SqlDbType.Char, 6).Value = obj.PortStatus;

                debug = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
    }
}
```

The parameters come from a dictionary/hashmap, `GlobalVariables.UpdateData`, that stores data rows as objects where the key is the serial number from that row of data(e.g. `Dictionary<string[serial Number], DictionaryObjs>)` and the values of the fields for each data row are stored as strings, in a class called `DictionaryObjs`. This is the parent class for all record types. In this case the record type is `OrgDevRepObj`.

I was able to get the code to work once, but I haven't been able to replicate it. It doesn't throw any errors, but I know its not working because `sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns a -1 for each dictionary key value pair. I've also tried using

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue('@Param', [value]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How much data are you loading? Merging data one line at at time is going to get _very_ slow for large amounts of data (10's of thousands of rows). A much faster approach is to load the CSV data into tables and work on the data in the database. However I can understand that if your strength is in C# rather than T-SQL, you might prefer to do it this way. If you actually want to debug, the next step I would suggest is use SQL Profiler to observe the SQL that is being executed.

Comment: You are using the wrong connection string? Or you're looking at the wrong database? The -1 often means you have "SET NOCOUNT ON" in your stored procedure. Do you have any triggers on the table? OR there are no records with `serialID = @SerialNumber`

Comment: Could you possibly have set NOCOUNT ON globally? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176031.aspx  try adding `SET NOCOUNT OFF` to your stored procedure. Have you looked in the DB to see if a change actually happened rather than relying on the returned count?

Comment: If you call the stored procedure from SSMS does it work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It's around 10 thousand. I've actually been able to the load the data in tables very quickly with the use of Dictionary in C#, it's essentially a hash map and I can use it to enforce unique records. Also there's almost no uniformity and duplicates in the CSV files' data fields unfortunately so it would be a Relational nightmare to load them into tables as is, so it has to be manipulated before it's put into each table in the DB. My strength is C# though.

Comment: @Jeremey Thompson, I know the connection string is good, because I use the same one in another stored procedure that is used to get data for output (a select statement with a few joins).

Comment: @IanMercer I will have to try setting no count to off and making sure its not globally enabled. I will also try calling from SSMS to double check, but I'm pretty sure it works.

Comment: @IanMercer Adding `Set NOCOUNT OFF` Fixed it! All I had to do after that was explicitly define the VarChar length for Serial number as it was truncating the string for the serial number I was passing to it. Works great now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you possibly have set `NOCOUNT ON` globally? See msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176031.aspx

Try adding `SET NOCOUNT OFF` to your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

An idea to test according to your situation, create a table called test with a single varchar type field and inside the procedure you make an insert to that table by inserting the SerialNumber. This way you can tell if it is filtering by the correct serial and if the procedure is executed. Luck…